# Display markers one by one after 3 seconds using setTimeOut.. Why it shows only the last marker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to display the markers one by one using setTimeOut but it is not working. here is my code:

```
function showOneByOne(arrayOfMarkersObj) {
    for (u in arrayOfMarkersObj) {           
        setTimeout(function() {      
            arrayOfMarkersObj[u].setVisible(true);
        }, 3000);
    }
}
```

The problem is that It is showing only the last marker on the map and not all the markers. However if I put

`arrayOfMarkersObj[u].setVisible(true);`

outside of setTimeOut, It shows all markers.

Why is it happeneing?

Comment: Closure is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the keys to an array (if you are solely on ECMA5 capable browsers you can use as suggested in comments the [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) instead :

```
var keys = [];
for (u in arrayOfMarkersObj)
    keys.push(u); //assuming arrayOfMarkersObj is an object not an array?
```

Now go one by one in your `setTimeout`:

```
var current = 0;

function reveal() {
    arrayOfMarkersObj[keys[current++]].setVisible(true);
    if (current < keys.length) setTimeout(reveal, 3000);
}
reveal();
```

If you want the first delayed switch the last line with:

```
setTimeout(reveal, 3000);
```

The reason why the example in the post doesn't work is because `u` is not available to `setTimeout` at the time it is called. The code invoked by the event `setTimeout` sets is invoked on the `window` object.

In order to make the var available you need to store it a "level up" typically the global scope or inside the wrapping function (by `that = this` for a reference as `this` becomes `window`, then use `that` inside `setTimeout`) to access it.

Comment: `var keys = Object.keys(arrayOfMarkersObj)` - just sayin'

Comment: of course, if that variable actually _is_ an array, you shouldn't use `for ... in` _or_ `Object.keys()`.

Comment: @Alnitak For ECMA5 capable browsers that is fine. Leaving it as-is for simplicity. Thanks anyways :) I have no idea what he stores in that object (array?) so I'll do the same as the focus is setTimeout not working.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, the value of a variable in an inner scope is bound the scope where the variable is defined. Which means that the callback, when executed, will retrieve the value of `u` from the scope where `u` was defined, that is `showOneByOne()`. Therefore `u` will be equal to `arrayOfMarkersObj.length -1` (the final value after the `for` cycle) for every execution of the callback.

One easy way to solve should be using [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), even though it's not clear the need for different callbacks/timers for each element. You might as well use a single one as suggested in the answer by **Ken - Abdias Software**.